# Android MediaPlayer фоновое воспроизведение

Tags: mediaplayer, android

Создал:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(FILENAME);
mp.prepare();
```

запустил:

```
mp.start
```

Играет даже когда Activity onDestroy()
В заного открытом Activity создается mp и играет музыка поверх уже запущенного mp

Вопрос: как возобновить управление уже запущенного mp во вновь открытом Activity (после onDestroy())?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо выносить запуск `MediaPlayer` в `Service`, либо уничтожать `MediaPlayer` в `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 2):

Он будет играть пока ты не сделаешь mp.stop(), или mp.reset(), или mp.release(), ну или система сама его не убьет.

Вообще желательно вписать в Activity onDestroy(): mp.release()
Тогда плеер остановится и высвободит занятые ресурсы.

И вообще, если с плеером проблемы, глянь на диаграму и сразу все ясно будет: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Для того чтобы управлять плеером из нескольких активити, сделай сервис и положи плеер туда. Вот что нужно знать:
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection.html
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/163-urok-98-service-lokalnyj-binding.html